Custom Converter for java.nio.file.Path not working in Spring Boot
For unit testing, I'd like to use an in-memory filesystem (like jimfs) to setup the test environment. For this purpose, I registered a  custom Converter<String, Path> with @ConfigurationPropertiesBinding, but it does not work.
In my sample project I'm using Spring Boot 3.3.1 and Kotlin 2.0.0.
A Git-Repo with MRE can be found here: https://github.com/woolph/spring-boot-path-converter
For my purpose, I register a Converter<String, Path> to return a Path object created by the in-memory filesystem like this:
@Configuration
class TestFileSystemConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun fileSystem(): FileSystem = Jimfs.newFileSystem(com.google.common.jimfs.Configuration.unix())

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
    fun fileSystemPathConverter(fileSystem: FileSystem): Converter<String, Path>
        = FileSystemPathConverter(fileSystem)

    class FileSystemPathConverter(
        val fileSystem: FileSystem,
    ) : Converter<String, Path> {
        override fun convert(source: String): Path {
            return fileSystem.getPath(source)
        }
    }
}

I'd expect that a configuration resolving properities of type Path would be assigned with an Path object referring to the in-memory filesystem (instead of the FileSystems.getDefault())
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("test.filesystem")
class TestConfiguration {
    lateinit var path: Path
}

But this is not the case. Some other converter seems to take precedence over my custom one.
Researching the topic I stumbled upon similar issues, which apparently should be solved in Spring Boot 3.3.1. But this specific issue still persist. Can anybody tell me, how to do this?

try @Primary on the bean

Thanks for the input, @sidgate ! Unfortunately adding the @Primary annotation to the fileSystemPathConverter bean does not change the behavior. The path is still created with default file system.
